# If a Compact $n$-Manifold Immerses in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is there a Locally Flat Immersion?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, 4-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is a compact, topological $n$-manifold and there is a topological immersion (i.e. local embedding) of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Is there necessarily a locally flat immersion of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?  Are there any $n > 3$ for which it's known to be true?

It's related to this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115222/is-every-compact-n-manifold-that-immerses-in-mathbbrn1-smoothable

Comment: For embeddings the answer is in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864186900477, [Resolving wild embeddings of codimension-one manifolds in manifolds of dimensions greater than 3, by Fredric Ancel]. "Tame" is defined on p.16.